# How to improve the following codes for generating eigenvalues?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

The following codes generates eigenvalues by using Cebyshev Collocation method of two matrix which consists of another matrices. The codes take more calculation time for larger collocation points, say n=500. How to improve them for faster calculation? Thanks in advance.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
n = Input["Please Enter the number of Collcation points N you want:"];
beta = 1.0; ita = 1.0; F = 1.0;(*parameters*)
y = Table[Cos[(j*Pi)/n], {j, 0, n}];(*Definig Collocation points*)
z[x_] := RecurrenceTable[{t[i + 1] == 2.0*x*t[i] - t[i - 1], t[0] == 1.0,t[1] == x}, t, {i, 0, n}]
T = {}; Do[AppendTo[T, z[y[[k]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}](*Defining T matrix*)
zDer[x_] := z'[x];Tprime = {}; Do[AppendTo[Tprime, zDer[y[[k]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}]; (*Defining Tprime matrix*)

(*Defining all the funtions we need*)
Z[x_] := (x + 1.0)/2.0;
v[Z_] := Exp[(F/4.0*ita)*Z];
vDer[Z_] := v'[Z];
a[Z_] := 1/Exp[(F/4.0*ita)*Z];
aDer[Z_] := a'[Z];
b[Z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0*ita)*Z] + ((4*beta)/F)*(Exp[-(F/4.0*ita)*Z])*((Exp[-(F/4.0*ita)*Z]) - 1.0);
bDer[Z_] := b'[Z];
 
(*creating all the matrix we need*)
Vbar1 = {}; Do[AppendTo[Vbar1, v[Z[y[[k]]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}]
Vbar = DiagonalMatrix[Vbar1];(*creating V_bar Matrix*)
Vbarprime1 = {}; Do[AppendTo[Vbarprime1, vDer[Z[y[[k]]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}]
Vbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[Vbarprime1];(*creating V_bar_Prime Matrix*)
Abar1 = {}; Do[AppendTo[Abar1, a[Z[y[[k]]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}]
Abar = DiagonalMatrix[Abar1];(*creating A_bar Matrix*)
Abarprime1 = {}; Do[AppendTo[Abarprime1, aDer[Z[y[[k]]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}]
Abarprime = DiagonalMatrix[Abarprime1];(*creating A_bar_prime Matrix*)
Bbar1 = {}; Do[AppendTo[Bbar1, b[Z[y[[k]]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}]
Bbar = DiagonalMatrix[Bbar1];(*creating B_bar Matrix*)
Bbarprime1 = {}; Do[AppendTo[Bbarprime1, bDer[Z[y[[k]]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}]
Bbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[Bbarprime1];

(* creating entries of the final U and W matrix below*)
P = 2.0*Vbar . Tprime + Vbarprime . T;
Q = Abarprime . T + 2.0*Abar . Tprime;
R = Bbarprime . T + 2.0*Bbar . Tprime;
S = 2.0*Bbar . Vbarprime - 2.0*Bbar . Vbar + (beta/ita)*Abar;
L = 3.0*Abar . Vbarprime + 1.0 - 2.0*Vbar . Abarprime - (F/ita);
K = 3.0*Abar . Bbar + Abar . Bbarprime + 2.0*Bbar . Abarprime;
ST = S . T;
LT = L . T;
KT = K . T;

(*U={{T,0,0},{0,T,0},{0,0,T}};*)
U = Fold[ArrayFlatten[{{#, 0}, {0, #2}}] &, T, {T, ConstantArray[0, {n + 1, n + 1}]}];
(*W={{-P,0,-Q},{(-beta/ita)*T,-P,-R},{ST,LT,KT}}*)
W = ArrayFlatten[{{-P, 0, -Q}, {-(beta/ita)*T, -P, -R}, {ST, LT,KT}}];
{Vals, Vecs} = Eigensystem[{W, U}];
Vals
ListPlot[Vals]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bottleneck are the lines

```
zDer[x_] := z'[x];
Tprime = {}; Do[AppendTo[Tprime, zDer[y[[k]]]], {k, 1, n + 1}];
```

*Mathematica* has to submit a symbolic `x` to `z` and then to take the derivative symbolically. Since it has to apply the product rule, this leads to  complexity $O(n^2)$ with a large constant due to symbolic calculations. Since it has to do that for each `k` from `1` to `n + 1`, computing `Tprime` this ways takes $O(n^3)$ time.

However, it is quite straight-forward to implement the recurrence tables for `T` and `Tprime` together in just one routine -- just by applying the product rule in each step.

```
ClearAll[recurrenceTables];
recurrenceTables[x_?VectorQ, n_] := Module[{T, Tprime},
   T = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
   Tprime = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
   T[[1]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
   T[[2]] = x;
   
   Tprime[[1]] = ConstantArray[0., Length[x]];
   Tprime[[2]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
   
   Do[
    T[[i]] = 2. x T[[i - 1]] - T[[i - 2]];
    Tprime[[i]] = 2. T[[i - 1]] + 2. x Tprime[[i - 1]] - Tprime[[i - 2]];
    , {i, 3, n + 1}];
   
   {Transpose[T], Transpose[Tprime]}
   ];
```

Cleaning out a couple of other coding issues, by code looks like this:

```
n = 120;
(*parameters*)
beta = 1.0;
ita = 1.0;
F = 1.0;

(*Definig Collocation points*)
y = Cos[N[Pi/n] Range[0., n]];
{T, Tprime} = recurrenceTables[y, n];

(*Defining all the functions we need*)
Z[x_] := (x + 1.0)/2.0;
v[Z_] := Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z];
a[Z_] := 1/Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z];
b[Z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z] + ((4.0 beta)/F) (Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z])((Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z]) - 1.0);

Zy = Map[Z, y];
Vbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v, Zy]]];
Vbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v', Zy]]];

Abar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a, Zy]]];
Abarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a', Zy]]];

Bbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[b, Zy]]];
Bbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[b', Zy]]];


(*creating entries of the final U and W matrix below*)
P = 2.0 Vbar . Tprime + Vbarprime . T;
Q = Abarprime . T + 2.0 Abar . Tprime;
R = Bbarprime . T + 2.0 Bbar . Tprime;
S = 2.0 Bbar . Vbarprime - 2.0 Bbar . Vbar + (beta/ita) Abar;
L = 3.0 Abar . Vbarprime + 1.0 - 2.0 Vbar . Abarprime - (F/ita);
K = 3.0 Abar . Bbar + Abar . Bbarprime + 2.0 Bbar . Abarprime;
ST = S . T;
LT = L . T;
KT = K . T;

U = ArrayFlatten[{{T, 0., 0.}, {0., T, 0.}, {0., 0., 0. T}}];
W = ArrayFlatten[{{-P, 0., -Q}, {-(beta/ita) T, -P, -R}, {ST, LT, KT}}];
{Vals, Vecs} = Eigensystem[{W, U}];
Vals
ListPlot[Vals, PlotRange -> All]
```

For `n = 500` this takes about 10 seconds on my machine. And almost all the time is due to `Eigensystem`.

By the way: Reading your comments in the code I got the hunch that your implementation of `U` is not what you intended. So I corrected it, too.

Comment: Thank you so much Henrik. I really appreciate your help. One more question, why could not it plot all the eigenvalues?

Comment: Maybe some eigenvalues had nonzero imaginary part. Even if the true eigenvalues should all be real, numerical errors might lead to (small) nonzero imaginary parts. (If they are not small then this might be an indication of some coding error.) If you are sure that the eigenvalues should be real, then you can discard the imaginary parts with `Re`.

Comment: Eigen values here are complex but we need to find and plot finite complex eigenvalues only.

Comment: Dear Henrik, I noticed you put an extra T in my U matrix, but it does not exist in my system of equations. However, when I removed it , matrix dimension does not agree for finding Eigensystem. How would  I be able to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I correct it now (I just inserted a `0.` before the last `T`. Is it that what you want?

Comment: Yes, codes seem working fine now. Thanks again.